# Turning a result into a const

Tags: node.js

Admitting I'm a very newbie dev

I'm writing my first app not following/adding into existing code.

I'd like to set a const from an api, the field is totalGames

Url for reference http://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/schedule/games/?sportId=1

Field is the 4th line

In nodejs I can get it to console the result I want out with this

```
const request = require('postman-request')
const MLBStatsAPI = require('mlb-stats-api')
const { response } = require('express')
const mlbStats = new MLBStatsAPI()

const url = 'http://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/schedule/games/?sportId=1'

request ({url:url}, (error,response) => {
    const todaygames = JSON.parse(response.body)
    console.log(todaygames.totalGames)
})
```

I would like to keep that result (in today's example: 14) as a value I can work from.

I would think you should be able to change

const todaygames = JSON.parse(response.body)

to

const todaygames = JSON.parse(response.body.totalGames)

console.log(todaygames)

and get the result I want, but it comes back with

```
  undefined:1
    undefined
^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Request._callback (/Users/jamescpower/BaseballApp/src/app.js:30:29)
```

Comment: My guess is that `response.body.totalGames` is already an object

Comment: It might be, so how do you store it for use?

Comment: Or if `response.body` is a JSON string you cannot navigate into it until AFTER it is parsed into an object

Comment: When you do, `const todaygames = JSON.parse(response.body)`, what is the result of, `console.log(todaygames)`?

Comment: Gives too much data back
 totalItems: 14,
  totalEvents: 0,
  totalGames: 14,
  totalGamesInProgress: 0,
  dates: [
    {
      date: '2021-03-11',
      totalItems: 14,
      totalEvents: 0,
      totalGames: 14,
      totalGamesInProgress: 0,
      games: [Array],
      events: []
    }
  ]
}

Comment: That may be true (too much data back), but it is the object of data you are getting back. You must parse the result from the request into an object then work with that object's data as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [deconstruct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the result to the variable you want, assuming the object is something like:

```js
{
  totalGames: 10,
  someOtherField: {
    data: 'more-data',
    foo: 'bar',
  },
}
```

```js
request ({url:url}, (error,response) => {
    const { totalGames } = JSON.parse(response.body)
    console.log(totalGames)
})
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!  Where do I read more to understand it?  Just keep googling deconstruct?

Comment: @lasombrra I had linked a deconstructing explanation at Mozilla in the answer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution:

```
const res = JSON.parse(response.body)
const todaysgames = res.totalgames
```

Why your solution does not work:

Lets say there is an object `const obj = {name: 'foo'}`. Here we can get the value `foo` by `obj.name` because obj is an object.
Here `reponse.body` is a string. You cannot just `mystringvariable.name` to strings, to do that `response.body` must be parsed to an object. `JSON.parse` is doing that job.

When you

```
    const todaygames = JSON.parse(response.body)
    console.log(todaygames.totalGames)
```

its works because `response.body` is parsed to an object, then you access its `totalgames`

When you

```
    const todaygames = JSON.parse(response.body.totalGames)
    console.log(todaygames)
```

it does not work because, `response.body` isn't parsed, its just a string. you have to parsed it first to access its properties
In order to things work, first you want to parse it to a string, then access it

Comment: Okay, I think I"m following.  The value I want is 'totalGames'.  So I get there with my original code and the parsing is done.  How do I turn that into a const? So I can use it elsewhere?

Comment: @iasombrra parse the response, set the value to a const `const res = JSON.parse(response.body);
const todaysgames = res.totalgames;`

Comment: or you can use `const {totalGames} = JSON.parse(response.body);`. This one is called object deconstruction. Same thing in less lines

Comment: const res = JSON.parse(response.body)

const todaysgames = res.totalgames

console.log(todaysgames)

Gets me this error
undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jamescpower/BaseballApp/src/app.js:28:18)

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc

> json - sets body to JSON representation of value and adds Content-type: application/json header. Additionally, parses the response body as JSON.

so if you you do this it should work like you expect

```
const url = 'http://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/schedule/games/?sportId=1';
request({ url, json: true }, (error, response) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const { totalGames } = response.body;
    console.log(totalGames);
  }
});
```